# Logcat on android L not clearing after unplugging and reconnecting

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm running a script which copies logcat to a file every 10 seconds:

```
:start
set timestamp=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

adb logcat -d > "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Log\%timestamp%-logcat.txt"

adb logcat -c

timeout /t 10
goto start
```

This works great until I unplug the device(Nexus 7 running on Android L) and plug it back in.
After this the reading still works, but it doesn't clear anymore( adb logcat -c ), so i get a larger and larger file. I have to restart the device to be able to clear the log again. I think it might have something to do with writing permission.

Edit: also doesn't work if I write adb logcat -c in a console.

Comment: What language is your script in? Bash? Batch? perhaps try adding that as a tag

Comment: @CarCzar It's in batch, but the problem has not really much to do with the script. When I write the command in a console it also doesn't work, so I don't really need a batch expert to look at this.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, for me logcat -c won't clear buffer unless I reboot my device. Were you able to fix this problem?

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal Sorry, I was not able find a solution. I was hoping this would be fixed in later android itterations.

Answer (score 0):

So whilst `logcat -c` should work great there is [Issue 78916](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78916).  The suggested workaround is:

`NOW=$(date +"%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000") ; adb logcat -T "$NOW"`

Comment: Thanks. I think they describe the exact opposite situation where they can't clear until the disconnect and reconnect. For me that's when the problem starts. But I don't have my android device anymore, so if someone can reproduce the problem and confirm this works (on my bug, not Issue 78916) I will mark it as The Answer.